# OpenGL application, The Black Screen of Faliure

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, glsl, lwjgl

Without the perspective projection and view matrix my scene is fine:
[image: good rendering]

If i use the camera the result is weird:
[image: not so good rendering]

When i'm using the projection combined with view/camera matrix i always(even if move in every direction) get an empty screen or as i like to call it: the "Black Screen of Faliure".

## Here's the matrices i pass to the VS:

Model Mat4: (model rotation on x-axis)

```
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.4888726 0.8723553 0.0 
0.0 -0.8723553 0.4888726 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

View Mat4: (Camera slightly moved and rotated on y-axis)

```
0.94107544 0.0 0.33819667 -0.53266037 
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 
-0.33819667 0.0 0.94107544 2.4321942 
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```

Projection Mat4:

```
1.299038 0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 1.7320509 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 1.002002 -2.002002 
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
```

perspective proj calculation:

```
thf=tan(torad(60)/2); ar=800/600; zn=1; zf=1000;

1/(thf*ar) 0 0 0
0 1/thf 0 0 
0 0 (-zn-zf)/(zn-zf) 2*zn*zf/(zn-zf) 
0 0 1 0
```

My Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330

attribute layout(location = 0) vec3 Position;
attribute layout(location = 1) vec3 TexCoord;
attribute layout(location = 2) vec3 Normal;
out vec3 TexCoords;
uniform mat4 Model;
uniform mat4 View;
uniform mat4 Projection;

void main(){
        
    gl_Position = Projection * View * Model * vec4(Position, 1);
    TexCoords=TexCoord;     
}
```

Comment: are you testing compilation success, most framework will give you understandable compilation failure. Past your fragment shader too, vertex seems normal...Are really your TexCoord in 3d, are they not vec2 instead?

Comment: The program is successfully compiled and linked. For the moment i use 2D tex coords but the final goal is actually to extend my application to 3d mapped textures.

Comment: Did you by any chance scaled the projection matrix? A projection matrix should be orthonormal.

Comment: Your projection matrix looks ***very*** odd. Particularly the fact that the second and third rows appear to have 5 columns. Likewise, the third column is missing values.

Comment: @CommuSoft i've checked and i didn't scale the projection matrix, that matrix is result of the calculation i've posted below.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman i'm sorry for my mistakes, i've corrected my formula and hopefully now it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there sometimes a boolean can screw you badly.

```
 glUniformMatrix4(UniformHandle, true, ubo); // true for row-major order
```